# Is every human wizard a female?

Tags: little-witch-academia

In both LWA series and OVA, I only saw female wizards. The most likely to be a male wizard are Lotte's dad and the magical shop owner but I never actually see them perform any magic. There are also several non-human male character like  the Dragon Fafnir, but every human male seems to be a muggle. Is there any human male wizard in LWA world? If there are none, why all of them is female?

Comment: There appeared to be men at the Wild Hunt, but it wasn't clear if they were male magic users or some kind of spirits.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Nope, we see a wizard who is pretty clearly male in episode 25 at timestamp 21:26. (Behind Croix, wearing glasses.)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot / retranscription of the dialogue? :)

Comment: @Ikaros I just did :)

Answer (score 1):

The series never states the existence or non-existence of human male magic users.

While we can assume from the setting that wizards likely don't exist, the best answer is:

We don't really know.